# How to "Delete Inherited Columns on a Child table "

Tags: postgresql

I have created a Child table that inherits the columns from 2 other tables . 
Now i need to delete some columns ONLY from the child table , is that possible ?

I've tried deleting with ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN . 
I've also tried doing it from the options , but i get the popup "This object is not user editable "

```
//Creating the Child Table//
CREATE TABLE accidentinfo_year2010
(CHECK (EXTRACT (YEAR FROM timeline) = '2010' ) ) ; 
INHERITS (accidentinfo , vehicleinfo ) ;



//Trying to Delete some columns//
ALTER TABLE accidentinfo_year2010
DROP COLUMN accident ,
DROP COLUMN severity , 
DROP COLUMN timeline , 
DROP COLUMN area , 
DROP COLUMN weathercondition , 
DROP COLUMN year  , 
DROP COLUMN inscotland , 
DROP COLUMN vehicleage , 
DROP COLUMN model , 
DROP COLUMN sexofdriver , 
DROP COLUMN vehicletype ;
```

I need to delete the specified columns , either by code or through the properties .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in an easy way. The column is inherited and if you do not want to inherit some of the columns you need to declare a table that does not inherit those columns.

Perhaps you need more abstract table to inherit before the ones your table inherits currently.

So the best you can do - maybe not the best method - is to:

1. create more abstract table(s) to be inherited (if needed) with only needed columns
2. make your table with dropped columns to inherit it
3. copy data from needed colums to that new table
4. copy the data excluding the unwanted columns to another table that does not inherit the tables with unwanted columns